# Artihmetic overflow error when string into a smalldatetime

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I have a program that uses DateTime.Now.ToString() to get the time and then plugs it into a coloum that is smalldatetime. This worked before but now I get this error.

"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
The statement has been terminated."

What am I doing wrong?

This is my SQL statement

```
command.CommandText = @" INSERT INTO Mail1 (UserID, Subject, Feedback, Date_Sent_On)
                         VALUES (@UserID, @Subject, @Feedback, @Date_Sent_On)";
```

Comment: why using smalldatetime?

Comment: Alter your DateTime field in the Database to DateTime or Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Date_Sent_On` parameter should be of type `DateTime` instead of `string` and you should pass `DateTime.Now` as its value.

Using `DateTime.Now.ToString()` is very unreliable, because formatting the date with `ToString()` is culture dependent - it can produce different results depending on the regional settings of your computer and the culture settings in the application.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use

```
requestdatetime between '7/1/2011' and GETDATE()
```

in your SQL statement to get the current date.

I've also found it helpful at times to use something like this:

```
SELECT 
  cast(datepart(mm, M.REquestdatetime) as varchar) + '/'
  + cast(datepart(yy, M.REquestdatetime) as varchar) as [Day]
FROM ...
```

This gives you flexibility in terms of displaying results as `MM-YYYY`, etc.